# make container div take up as much space as needed

Tags: html, css

I have a container div that contains another container. I want my outer container to take up the space needed if screen size allows it to do so but I keep getting a scrollbar none the less.

```css
.outer {
  padding: 16px;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Some content...
  </div>
</div>
```

inner div has no styling and defaults to display block;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: *I want my outer container to take up the space needed if screen size allows it to do so* space needed for what ? what space vertical or horizontal ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948202/make-div-expand-to-take-all-the-available-space

Comment: Horizontal. It's a tooltip of which the content is approximately 400px wide but the tooltip takes up approximately 100px although there is space for it to take up more.

Comment: @C-lara Unfortunately no..

Comment: @Maria and you want it always to grow with screen or to you want to stop at 400 px when the screen is e.g. 800 px?

Comment: @C-lara I want to have a max-width of i.e. 400 px.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to let the div grow with the content, you can define it like that: Don't define width and/or height, then the div element grows along with its content. But the content must **not** be set to absolute! If the content is set to float, you have to set to the container to

```
overflow:hidden
```

then it will grow with content. You can still define a max-with:

```
max-width: 400px;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well.  This helps for setting a container of a specific width with scrollable content but unfortunately that's not what I'm after. If the content is less then 400px in I don't want the container to take up 400ps. Let's say the content take up 50 px I want the container to be 50px wide.

Comment: Thanks @C-lara I still have the problem of the container not taking up as much space as possible though. The container is approximately 20px wide although the content is 100px. I tried adding width: 100% but then I get a lot of white-space after the content.

Comment: Maybe you can play around a bit with the percentage... Try 80%, 60%, 40%... But take in mind that this becomes a bit more complicated when you want to have a responsive design. You may end up defining the width for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was a position absolute deep down inside a div inside my container div. That's why the content would not  expand.